# How do you know you're close to the solution?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, simulated-annealing, n-queens

I've searched but found no answer.

I'm trying to solve the 8 queens puzzle (more specifically the N queens puzzle) using the simulated annealing (SA) algorithm implemented in Java, but I'm kinda stuck when it comes to the objective function. How do I know if I'm close to my target (the optimal solution) or not?

I've come up with two ways to give attempts "points" (the more points to better the attempt):

1. how many queens are on the board legally
2. how many queens are on the board legally + the amount of avaliable spots for the next queen to be legally placed

But I can't decide if these are any good. Are you guys able to provide me with some hints or any other input? :)

Comment: [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#simulatedAnnealing) is an image that shows how simulated annealing solves 4 queens. At every state, the score (= points) is shown, which are - like Dukeling says - the number of pairs of queens that can attack each other. At any given state, all queens are on the board, each in their own column. The starting state is often random or all queens on the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance from the solution is typically defined as the number of queens attacking each other.

One approach taken with simulated annealing is to *randomly* place *all* the queens and then to select a random queen that's being attacked and move it to a random column in the same row.

Rather than trying to place them one by one.

**Isn't this just the same as a random solution then?**

No.

We pick a random move, but the probability of this move actually happening depends on how good the move is and how close we are to the solution.

A good move will always happen, but, if it's a bad move, the probability of the move actually happening starts of high, but then gets lower and lower as we get closer to the solution. So, there's still a chance of making a bad move, so it will get out of a bad spot eventually, but overall, it mainly tries to make good moves.

This is the fundamental idea behind [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing#Overview) - it has an idea of a 'temperature' (which is related to the distance to the solution) - as the temperature gets lower (it gets closer to the solution), the probability of making bad moves decreases.

**Why not just pick the best move as we get closer to the solution?**

This will also work, as long as there's still a chance of picking a bad move (though I'm not sure this will still classify as simulated annealing, or whether this will lead to a performant solution - analysing all moves at each step would be fairly expensive).

There needs to be a chance of a bad move because sometimes you need to move away from a local optimum, one where say only two queens are attacking each other, but you can't directly get from there to the solution - and the reverse of the best move will be best move in the next step.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that "close to" is defined very well here.  Thinking of all the places you could put successive queens as a tree structure, you could build a pretty deep branch that was an entirely wrong branch.  This can occur with other algorithms ([A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) comes to mind) where you could be very close indeed "as the crow flies", but still a long ways from a solution.

More technically, I'm wondering if you are lacking a proper [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29) for your problem; i.e., one satisfying the four properties given in the link, which you give you a solid way to define "close to".

Comment: Simulated annealing is a well-known way of solving this problem. 'Close to' is not *exactly* defined, but it's well-enough defined for simulated annealing to work.

Comment: @Dukeling Of course SA can solve the problem---but that's beside the point.  It does not admit a metric for how close it is to a solution.

Comment: But the fact that SA can solve the problem is exactly my point - whichever metric you use in your SA algorithm is equivalent to (roughly) how close you are to a solution. And whether or not you agree with this, the question is about SA, which you seem to have missed / are ignoring.